# API authentication with swift

Tags: ios, swift, api

I want to make a GET request to an api. I have an api key but don't know how to implement it with my swift app. The API documentation says this:

"API requests must be made over HTTPS and be accompanied by an API Key sent via the X-IFL-API-Key header."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSMutableURLRequest` and simply add the header:

```
request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-IFL-API-Key")
```

You can find the documentation for `NSMutableURLRequest` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/). Once you have created and configured your URL request, you can "invoke" it by using the various methods of `NSURLSession`.